# C++ , Timer, Milliseconds

Tags: c++, timer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>



using namespace std;

double diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2)
{
    double diffticks=clock1-clock2;
    double diffms=(diffticks)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    return diffms;
}
int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i=0;;i++)
    {

    if(i==10000)break;
    }
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << diffclock(start,end)<<endl;

    getch();
return 0;
}
```

So my problems comes to that it returns me a 0, well to be stright i want to check how much time my program does operate... 
I found tons of crap over the internet well mostly it comes to the same point of getting a 0 beacuse the start and the end is the same

This problems goes to C++ remeber : <

Comment: Any chance your optimizer is throwing out your for loop because it does nothing?  Perhaps add an assignment to a global inside.  Alos, even if it does work, you've got your start and end backwards so that the time will be negative.

Comment: Even if the loop isn't optimised out, there's a good chance that counting to 10000 takes less than a millisecond. Modern computers are quite fast.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you're trying to benchmark, the loop is probably not a good test.

Comment: The time required to execute the code between `start` and `end` **is 0**.

Comment: You also have a potential integer division problem depending on the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your system - change `double diffms=(diffticks)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)` to `double diffms=diffticks/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000.0)`.

Comment: Still goes sero seniors :) well the loop is working fine, but you know... if a compare is nothing to... k
and i changed 1000 to 1000.0

Comment: You are very likely not measuring any milliseconds: http://ideone.com/284HMb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance, it seems like you are subtracting the larger value from the smaller value.  You call:

```
diffclock( start, end );
```

But then diffclock is defined as:

```
    double diffclock( clock_t clock1, clock_t clock2 ) {

        double diffticks = clock1 - clock2;
        double diffms    = diffticks / ( CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 );

        return diffms;
    }
```

Apart from that, it may have something to do with the way you are converting units.  The use of 1000 to convert to milliseconds is different on this page:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock

Comment: Okey mate, it works from the reference you gave, thou i tried it copule of times and it didnt, now i copied everything... and bang, miracle !
Thank you very much.
btw other guys
about the -1 thing... i dont know where you did read it... but if you hear yourself for a moment... -1-1= 0 to you?

Comment: @user2137666 -1 - (-1) == 0 for me. you?

Comment: +1. Also, please consider using cppreference instead. The cplus plus dot com is a commercial site full of ads. Cppreference is a community driver wiki-based reference that is a lot more up to date, and of course ad-free.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few problems in here. The first is that you obviously switched start and stop time when passing to `diffclock()` function. The second problem is optimization. Any reasonably smart compiler with optimizations enabled would simply throw the entire loop away as it does not have any side effects. But even you fix the above problems, the program would most likely still print 0. If you try to imagine doing billions operations per second, throw sophisticated out of order execution, prediction and tons of other technologies employed by modern CPUs, even a CPU may optimize your loop away. But even if it doesn't, you'd need a lot more than 10K iterations in order to make it run longer. You'd probably need your program to run for a second or two in order to get `clock()` reflect anything.

But the most important problem is `clock()` itself. That function is not suitable for any time of performance measurements whatsoever. What it does is gives you an **approximation** of processor time used by the program. Aside of vague nature of the approximation method that might be used by any given implementation (since standard doesn't require it of anything specific), POSIX standard also requires `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to be equal to `1000000` independent of the actual resolution. In other words — it doesn't matter how precise the clock is, it doesn't matter at what frequency your CPU is running. To put simply — it is a totally useless number and therefore a totally useless function. The only reason why it still exists is probably for historical reasons. So, please do not use it.

To achieve what you are looking for, people have used to read the [CPU Time Stamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) also known as "RDTSC" by the name of the corresponding CPU instruction used to read it. These days, however, this is also mostly useless because:

1. Modern operating systems can easily migrate the program from one CPU to another. You can imagine that reading time stamp on another CPU after running for a second on another doesn't make a lot of sense. It is only in latest Intel CPUs the counter is synchronized across CPU cores. All in all, it is still possible to do this, but a lot of extra care must be taken (i.e. once can setup the affinity for the process, etc. etc).
2. Measuring CPU instructions of the program oftentimes does not give an accurate picture of how much time it is actually using. This is because in real programs there could be some system calls where the work is performed by the OS kernel on behalf of the process. In that case, that time is not included.
3. It could also happen that OS suspends an execution of the process for a long time. And even though it took only a few instructions to execute, for user it seemed like a second. So such a performance measurement may be useless.

So what to do?

When it comes to profiling, a tool like [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) must be used. It can track a number of CPU clocks, cache misses, branches taken, branches missed, a number of times the process was moved from one CPU to another, and so on. It can be used as a tool, or can be embedded into your application (something like [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/)).

And if the question is about actual time spent, people use a wall clock. Preferably, a high-precision one, that is also not a subject to NTP adjustments (monotonic). That shows exactly how much time elapsed, no matter what was going on. For that purpose [`clock_gettime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html) can be used. It is part of SUSv2, POSIX.1-2001 standard. Given that use you `getch()` to keep the terminal open, I'd assume you are using Windows. There, unfortunately, you don't have `clock_gettime()` and the closest thing would be performance counters API:

```
BOOL QueryPerformanceFrequency(LARGE_INTEGER *lpFrequency);
BOOL QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount);
```

For a portable solution, the best bet is on [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock). It was introduced in C++11, but is supported by most industrial grade compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC).

Below is an example of how to use it. Please note that since I know that my CPU will do 10000 increments of an integer way faster than a millisecond, I have changed it to microseconds. I've also declared the counter as `volatile` in hope that compiler won't optimize it away.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    volatile int i = 0; // "volatile" is to ask compiler not to optimize the loop away.
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (i < 10000) {
        ++i;
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "It took me " << elapsed.count() << " microseconds." << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile and run it, it prints:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o test ./test.cpp && ./test
It took me 23 microseconds.
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be the loop is just too short. I tried it on my system and it gave 0 ticks. I checked what diffticks was and it was 0. Increasing the loop size to 100000000, so there was a noticeable time lag and I got -290 as output (bug -- I think that the diffticks should be clock2-clock1 so we should get 290 and not -290). I tried also changing "1000" to "1000.0" in the division and that didn't work.

Compiling with optimization does remove the loop, so you have to not use it, or make the loop "do something", e.g. increment a counter other than the loop counter in the loop body. At least that's what GCC does.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is available after c++11.

You can use **std::chrono** library.
std::chrono has two distinct objects. (**timepoint** and **duration**). Timepoint represents a point in time, and duration, as we already know the term represents an interval or a span of time.
This c++ library allows us to subtract two timepoints to get a duration of time passed in the interval. So you can set a starting point and a stopping point. Using functions you can also convert them into appropriate units.

Example using **high_resolution_clock** (which is one of the three clocks this library provides):

```
#include <chrono> 
using namespace std::chrono;
```

//before running function

```
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
```

//after calling function

```
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Subtract stop and start timepoints and cast it into required units using the duration_cast() function. Predefined units are nanoseconds, microseconds, milliseconds, seconds, minutes, and hours.

```
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
cout << duration.count() << endl;
```

Comment: How do you get the `duration` into something usable, like say an `unsigned long long` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should subtract end - start not vice versa.
Documentation says if value is not available clock() returns -1, did you check that?
What optimization level do you use when compile your program? If optimization is enabled compiler can effectively eliminate your loop entirely.

Comment: Well... its not a big error evenrually you get the same things with the minus, thou you are right that it should be swaped : )