# Understanding about clock() and CLOCKS_PER_SEC in C++

Tags: c++, c, time, timer, clock

I am interested in accurately timing a c++ application. There seems to be multiple definitions for "time", but for the sake of this question... I am interested in the time that I am counting on my watch in the real world... if that makes any sense! Anyway, in my application, my start time is done like this:

```
clock_t start = clock();
.
.
. // some statements
.
.
clock_t end = clock();
.
.
double duration = end - start;
.
.
cout << CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

**start** is equal to 184000
**end** is equal to 188000
**CLOCKS_PER_SEC** is equal to 1000000

Does this mean the duration (in seconds) is equal to 4000/1000000 ? If so, this would mean the duration is .004 seconds? Is there a more accurate way of measuring this?

Thank you

Comment: i think you are looking for [milliseconds in c++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235218/c-timer-milliseconds

Comment: hi garakchy. How can I capture the milliseconds here?

Comment: Is it true that milliseconds is equal to = diffticks / ( CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 ); ?

Comment: Ah yes.. if I do my math correctly...   Clocks x (1000 milliseconds / clocks per second) is equal to milliseconds

Comment: A small way to improve accuracy is the when calling `clock()`, code is _someplace_ within 0.0 to 1.0 clock ticks.  By doing `clock_t start,t; t = clock(); while ((start = clock()) == t);` will reduce the variation on the start time.  Not much help on the `end` call though.

Comment: `(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 )` is bad.  Say `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` was 999, then `(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 )`  is 0.  Better `(diffticks * 1000 + CLOCKS_PER_SEC/2)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, but then watch out for overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to find the time in nanoseconds precision

```
struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
/* Do something */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
```

It returns a value as `((((unsigned64)start.tv_sec) * ((unsigned64)(1000000000L))) + ((unsigned64)(start.tv_nsec))))`

If you find this helpful kindly refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572559/need-clear-idea-about-timespec-structure) link too..